# Mysql queries on Partitioned table in Laravel using Eloquent and not by Raw Queries

Tags: eloquent, partitioning

I have multi year database and is partitioned as per each year.
I am using Laravel framework for development.
I want to fire MySQL queries on this partitioned DB by using Eloquent.
I have tried by using raw queries and is possible. But I want to use Eloquent and not raw queries as I just want to replicate my old code (without partitioning) in new as per partitioned table where I have used Eloquent and do not want to change whole procedure.
Any help would be appreciated.